# Dependencies added in Android SDK are not working when using the SDK in other android app

Tags: android, sdk

I am developing an Android-SDK and I am using some libraries including [Lottie](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android)!. I have added the dependencies in SDK and generated aar file and published it on Jcenter. But after integrating the sdk in some other app, it shows errors on the libraries I have used. On adding the same libraries to that app, the errors disappear.

I have tried adding transitive=true and changing implementation to api too, but nothing worked.

There should be just single place where dependencies are to be added which will make integrating the SDK much easier.

Comment: First of all check if the pom file contains the transitive dependencies.

Comment: No, there is no pom file